# How to re-enable display after using unset DISPLAY

Tags: display

I recently installed `ubuntu` 17.10.1 after previously messing it up.So while I was reinstalling `Android Studio` I faced an issue where it refused to install.After following some tutorial I found out that the issue was running their installer script as Super User but before that another one had mislead me into using this command "unset DISPLAY" so now I can access my display devices and I badly need the night light feature.Please help.

Here is a screenshot of what I get in the display devices panel.Yet before using the command I could access it.[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKYdx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did you just try logging out and in again?  Anyway, the default value of the DISPLAY variable is :0
so to reset it:

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you

Comment: But logging out didnt help

Comment: It didnt work.I just tried it but I still get the same message as in the screenshot